# How to define variables correctly in qt function in R

Tags: r, statistics, distribution

for the question: `If T has the Student's t distribution with 5 degrees of freedom, find t so that 2*P(T > t) = 0.09` I basically tried all of the following and the answer is wrong. I am not yet really so connected with the R syntax and don't know how to use `qt`. Any idea?

```
> 1-qt(0.045,5)
[1] 3.097837
> qt(0.045,5)
[1] -2.097837
> 1-qt(0.09,5)
[1] 2.557869
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qt(0.09 / 2, 5, lower.tail = FALSE)
##[1] 2.097837
```

From `?qt`:

```
lower.tail: logical; if TRUE (default), probabilities are P[X <= x],
          otherwise, P[X > x].
```

Comment: Thank you. That solved the problem. Can you please tell me how this works and `qt(0.045,5)` doesn't ?